# Android calendar repeat event

Tags: android, events, calendar, recurring

I have a custom calendar in my android application that allows the user to create events with a start date and an optional recurrence. Frequency of recurrence is daily, weekly, monthly, yearly.when a user click one the item of calendar--day,he can see all events in this day. But how can I create a recurring event in sqlite.like google calendar App.

Look forwards to your help.Thanks sincerely. Sorry advance，I'm not good at english.